# Automator Service that opens URL from rich text

Tags: macos, automator, services

I would like to make an Automator Service that will open any link in a different browser (i.e. Firefox) than default (Safari).

Precisely: I want to right click on any link in Mac OS and select a service that will open that link in a Firefox.

Comment: Unless the _link text_ of the _hyperlink_ is the same as the _href attribute_, then I believe that what you're asking for is not doable with default _actions_ of an Automator Service. This is because when you right-click on a _hyperlink_, what gets passed to the Automator Service is the _link text_ not the _href attribute_ (URL), and as such there is no URL to pass to another _action_ to be acted upon. E.g. right-clicking on [Google](https://www.google.com">Google) passes "Google" to the service not the URL - i.e. `<a href="url">link text</a>` = `<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Automator action Extract URLs from Text.

[image]

Comment: This does not work, it simply gets nothing on the output.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with [Finicky](https://github.com/johnste/finicky) which is an open source application that allows you to routes links to different browsers based on rules you specify. For this to work, Finicky should be your default browser.

Finicky rules are specified in ~/.finicky.js. To specify links are to be sent to Safari by default and to Firefox when Command-clicking a link, use the following config in your ~/.finicky.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  defaultBrowser: "Safari",
  handlers: [
    {
      match: ({ keys }) => keys.command,
      browser: "Firefox"
    }
  ]
};
```

There many ways to specify rules. Check out their [README](https://github.com/johnste/finicky/blob/master/README.md) and [wiki](https://github.com/johnste/finicky/wiki).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using Automator to parse the text, use a Terminal (Bash) command to get the text you are looking for.

```
grep -o 'http://[^"]*' foobar.rtf
```

You can add this to Applescript

```
set varURL to do shell script "grep -o 'http://[^"]*' foobar.rtf"
```

The *simpliest* way to extract a URL and open a browser window to that URL is via Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

varURL=`grep -o 'http://[^"]*' ${1}`

open $varURL
```

I have a [sample.rtf](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmW50NkbWLGik7EjziKqpaETO4n-wg) file that I used to test this.  It's basically are Lorem Ipsum generated file with a URL embedded randomly in the text.

When I run the script,

```
$ ./urlxtract.sh sample.rtf
```

it opens my default browser at the URL it found.  To open it in a *different* browser, just replace the `open` line in the script with the following:

```
open -a "Firefox.app" $varURL
```

Comment: I need to put this into a service, as this seems to me the simplest way how to open an URL in a different browser, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: I understand and it works in Terminal, but not in automator Service. Even when I use the service just to run the file with the richtext as input, it opens nothing, just Firefox itself. It seems like the service does not get the link in the richtext input as it should. What I want: right click on any link in mail and select a service i.e. "Open in Firefox" -> the URL from that link should open in defined browser. What I use: an automator service with input as *richtext* in *any application* -> the service has only 1 action *Run shell script* with following code: `./urlxtract.sh "$@"`

Comment: You need to put *that* requirement in your question because as it's written, you are running a Bash command (`osascript` is called from Bash)

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand. Which requirement do you mean?

Comment: *What I want: right click on any link in mail and select a service*.  This requirement is completely different than what you are asking.  You want to open a link you right click on it and open it with a different browser; it has ***nothing*** to do with rich text.  This is a textbook definition of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I think I stated this clearly in the first sentence of my question: "I would like to make an Automator Service that will open any link in a different browser (i.e. Firefox) than default (Safari).". In the second sentence I wrote that the richtext is just my opinion = "AFAIK". I see now, that it was probably wrong ... anyhow, how can we move further to solve this please?

Answer (score -2):

You can of course change the default browser in System Preferences > General, if that's an easier solution.

Comment: Was this meant as a comment to another answer?

Comment: No. If the default browser is changed to FireFox, then clicking on links will go to that browser. It depends whether the OP wants to use FireFox particularly, or just "any non-default browser".

Comment: I read the question as "I want Safari as default and an easy way to open any link with Firefox".